# PCRE match after (lookbehind) with capture groups delimited by slashes and end of line

Tags: php, regex, pcre

My goal is a regex that captures {type} and {code} after propertyComplexity in the following string:-

```
/json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}/{code}
```

{type} and {code} are variables, could be anything or nothing e.g.

```
/json/score/propertyComplexity
```

I have started with the following expression:-

```
(?<=propertyComplexity)\/(.*)\/|$
```

But this only captures {type} between the 2 slashes; the end delimiter for the capture groups needs to be slash or end of line.

The regex needs to capture all words after slash after propertyComplexity until terminated by end of line. For example:

```
/json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}/{code}/{param3}/{param4}
```

Should yield 4 matches / capture groups; {type}, {code}, {param3}, {param4}

If it helps, this in the context of processing @path attributes in a WADL. The contents of the capture is actually irrelevant as it is the match count that will be used (in a comparison to the count of passed arguments in determining which WADL resource to call).

URL validity is not a requirement.

Matching on or after slash is not necessary when parameters in WADLs will always be encapsulated in {param} placeholders.

So I am simply using the following expression in a preg_match_all() == count($this->passedArgs)

```
/{(.*?)}/
```

Thank you everyone who contributed. Answer is being awarded to Jaytea.

Comment: I don't suppose newlines are accepted inside `{type}` and `{code}`, or are they?

Comment: New lines or other special characters will not appear between the slashes as the variables between slashes will form part of a URL

Comment: [`(?<=propertyComplexity)(?:\/([^\/\n]*))?(?:\/([^\/\n]*))?(?:\/|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/2XHJnQ/2) ?

Comment: Thanks Gurnam. Although not quite the right match. Have updated the post to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` combined with the following expression to achieve what you want:

```
/(?(?=^).*?propertyComplexity(?=(?:\/[^\/]+)*\/?$)|\G)\/\K([^\/]+)/
```

The '\G' assertion matches at the first position in the subject, which in this case effectively means that it matches at the position where the last match ended. The basic strategy here is to validate the format of the string at the beginning, then capture properties one at a time in subsequent rounds.

I'm not sure how strict you want to be with your validation, so I kept it quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution that combines a regex with `explode()`, as I'm pretty sure it's not possible to separately capture (or count) repeating groups, with PCRE.

The regex pattern expects any `/`-delimited segment after `/propertyComplexity` (I've prepended the slash for a little more rigor) to be non-empty and so allows for any non-empty content, not just content surrounded by curly brackets like `{type}`.

The pattern is a little more complex than it perhaps needs to be, but it makes exploding the result a little more brief (no need to trim slashes).

The actual argument values will be in the array `$arguments`, but I've left out displaying those values in the result to be a little more brief.

```
$urls = array(
  '/json/score/propertyComplexity',
  '/json/score/propertyComplexity/',
  '/json/score/propertyComplexity//', // invalid
  '/json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}',
  '/json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}/',
  '/json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}//', // invalid
  '/json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}/{code}',
  '/json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}/{code}/{param3}',
  '/json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}/{code}/{param3}/{param4}',
  '/json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}/{code}/{param3}/{param4}/{param5}'
);

foreach( $urls as $url ) {
  printf( 'testing %s' . PHP_EOL, $url );
  if( preg_match( '~(?<=/propertyComplexity)(?:/(?<arguments>[^/]+(/[^/]+)*))?(?:/?$)~', $url, $matches ) ) {
    $arguments = isset( $matches[ 'arguments' ] ) ? explode( '/', $matches[ 'arguments' ] ) : array();
    printf( '  URL is valid: argument count is %d' . PHP_EOL, count( $arguments ) );
  }
  else {
    echo '  URL is invalid' . PHP_EOL;
  }
  echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

<sup>[View this example on eval.in](https://eval.in/909638)</sup>

Result:

```
testing /json/score/propertyComplexity
  URL is valid: argument count is 0

testing /json/score/propertyComplexity/
  URL is valid: argument count is 0

testing /json/score/propertyComplexity//
  URL is invalid

testing /json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}
  URL is valid: argument count is 1

testing /json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}/
  URL is valid: argument count is 1

testing /json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}//
  URL is invalid

testing /json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}/{code}
  URL is valid: argument count is 2

testing /json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}/{code}/{param3}
  URL is valid: argument count is 3

testing /json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}/{code}/{param3}/{param4}
  URL is valid: argument count is 4

testing /json/score/propertyComplexity/{type}/{code}/{param3}/{param4}/{param5}
  URL is valid: argument count is 5
```